# Azure MySQL Server metrics retrieval from Storage - table or eventhub

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-monitoring, azure-mysql-database

I need to fetch "storage_percent", "io_consumption_percent" and "connections_failed" from Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers in Azure. I could not find any Rest API for same.
I tried to export data from Diagnostic Settings to Storage as well as Eventhub. But it did not work too.

Any way forward?

After this, I need to fetch the record from program and transfer to external system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All metrics are available using rest api call, after oauth2 authentication with microsoft.

Answer is here for all rest apis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/